# Reduce dataset to smaller size, keep the gist of information in the dataset

Tags: python, math, statistics

I'm developing a line chart. The data is being generated by a sensor and is a tuple (timestamp, value). Sensor creates a new datapoint every 60 seconds or so.

Now I want to display it in a graph and my limitation is about 900 points on then graph. In a daily view of that graph, I'd get about 1440 points and that's too much.

I'm looking for a general way how to shrink my dataset of any size to fixed size (in my case 900) while it keeps the timestamp distribution linear.

Thanks

Comment: You should add examples of input and output expected, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please clarify the requirement. Do you want the timestamp distribution to be exactly linear or is approximately linear good enough? Is some kind of "aliasing" allowed, where the results of two neighboring points are averaged together in some way?

Comment: At this point, I don't know yet. I'll go with what Pandas' resample can offer and see it in real life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to **resample** your data. Your current sample rate is 1/60 samples per second and you are trying to get to 1/96 samples per second (900 / (24*60*60)). The ratio between the two rates is 5/8.

If you search for "python resample" you will find other similar questions and articles involving numpy and pandas which have built in routines for it.

To do it manually you can first **upsample** by 5 to get to 7200 samples per second and then **downsample** by 8 to get down to 900 samples per second.

To upsample you can make a new list five times as long and fill in every fifth element with your existing data. Then you can do, say, linear interpolation to fill in the gaps.

One you do that you can downsample by simply taking every eighth element.

Comment: Yes, I found the correct term a few minutes after writing the question. I'm currently looking into Pandas' resample and how can it do what I need

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final solution using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_json('co2.json')

# calculates the 'rule' parameter for resampling
seconds = int(df.tail(1)[0]) - int(df.head(1)[0])
rule = seconds // 960

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='s')
df.resample('%sS' % rule).mean()
```